# How to add last 5 integers inputted from user in java?

Tags: java

```
int sum = 0;        
ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1;i<=schoolStart;i++)
{
  System.out.println("Percentage of students passing in"+" "+i+" is ");
  percentageOfPassingStudents = sc.nextInt();
  num.add(percentageOfPassingStudents);
  int count=0;          
  for(int j=0;;j++)
  {
     sum = sum+num.get(j);
  }
  count++;
}
```

I want the condition to check whether it is taking the last 5 values of array list.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: The last 5?  Then you need to do it out side the input loop and set the start condition of the loop to be `num.size() - 6` through to `num.size() - 1`

Comment: is there any other way...?

Comment: infinite loop? `for(int j=0;;j++)`

Comment: i want the condition there...

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the size of your arraylist is at least as big as the size of the schoolStart - 5 variable.

```
int sum = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1;i<=schoolStart;i++)
{
  System.out.println("Percentage of students passing in"+" "+i+" is ");
  percentageOfPassingStudents = sc.nextInt();
  num.add(percentageOfPassingStudents);
  int count=0;
  if(num.size() > schoolStart-5) {
    sum = sum+num.get(i-1);
  }
  count++;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this doesn't look like a good solution (to anything) - see avgvstvs solution for a better alternative

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at GoodSchool.isGoodSchool(GoodSchool.java:46)
 at GoodSchool.main(GoodSchool.java:68)

Comment: You should be able to figure that one out yourself - you're trying to add the last 5 numbers from a list that only has 4 numbers...

Comment: i am trying to input 10 numbers it is throwing an error at 5th input

Comment: That's because you're starting at i=1 and the first index of your arraylist is 0 - I changed it to reflect that.

Comment: import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class GoodSchool 

{
 String name;//name of the school
 int distance;//distance from home
 int numStudents;
 int numTeachers;
 String transportFacilities[];
 int percentageOfPassingStudents;
 int transportFac;//no.of ways of transport
 int schoolStart;//No.of years school started
 
 

 public boolean isGoodSchool()
 { 
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: System.out.println("Enter a School Name:");
   name = sc.nextLine();
   
   System.out.println("Enter distance from home:");
   distance = sc.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("Enter number of Students:");
   numStudents = sc.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("Enter number of Teachers:");
   numTeachers = sc.nextInt();
   
   System.out.println("No.of years school was started:");
   schoolStart = sc.nextInt();

Comment: int sum = 0;  
   ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(int i=1;i<=schoolStart;i++)
   {
     System.out.println("Percentage of students passing in"+" "+i+" is ");
     percentageOfPassingStudents = sc.nextInt();
     num.add(percentageOfPassingStudents);
     if(num.size()>schoolStart-5) 
     {
       sum = sum+num.get(i);
     }
   }

Comment: System.out.println("Avg. pass percentage of last 5 years is:"+(sum/5));


   if(((name!=null)&&(name.charAt(0)=='H'))&&(distance<5)&&((sum/5)>=90)||((numTeachers>=30)&&(numTeachers<=70))||(transportFac>=3))
   {
    return true;
   }
   else
   {
    return false;
   }
  
  }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  GoodSchool gs = new GoodSchool();
  gs.isGoodSchool();

 }

}

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a LinkedList and treat it like a Stack, if you only care about the last 5 integers input.

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
//Always add at the front of the list:
myList.addFirst(new Integer(2));


//asserting there are at least 5 items in the list:
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  Integer tmp = myList.removeFirst();
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: is there any other way to do it...?

Comment: Sure, using other variables to track positions.  You could achieve a similar effect with the ArrayList by storing ArrayList.size() and then calling ArrayList.remove(size - 1) in the loop.

Comment: That just wouldn't be my first option because why do arithmetic if you don't *have* to?

Comment: IMHO It doesn't really get any easier than the two suggestions I've offered.